# CSS Transitions: How to 'flash' in and out of a class

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make an element change instantly to a colour when I add a class, then slowly fade out when it's removed. I've achieved this with CSS transitions, like so:

```
.base {
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: 1.5s background-color;
}

.base.extra {
  transition: 0s background-color;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

This works, BUT only if I add the 'extra' class and then remove it as a separate action...

```js
$('#add').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.base').addClass('extra');
  }
)

$('#remove').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.base').removeClass('extra');
  }
)

$('#flash').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.base').addClass('extra');
    $('.base').removeClass('extra');
  }
)
```

```css
.base {
  width:300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: 1.5s background-color;
}
.base.extra {
  transition: 0s background-color;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='base'></div>
<a id=add>Add 'extra' class</a><br/>
<a id=remove>Remove 'extra' class</a><br/>
<a id=flash>Add then remove 'extra' class</a><br/>
```

If you click 'Add...' the block goes green, check.

If you click 'remove...' the block fades to black, check.

If you click 'Add then remove...' nothing changes!

---

I assume it's not changing the colour in the first instance, so it fades from black to black.

How can I make that third link change it to green, then instantly start fading with CSS transitions?

---

*Note:* I'm intentionally not using jQuery animations for this, as running a few dozen of them at one time presented a performance issue.

Comment: you need a kind of blink effect ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Possibly, I want an instant change followed by a long fade.

Comment: first are you aware that the event on the jquey is not correct? you ahve twice #remove ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks! I hadn't spotted that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st, you have two events for `#remove`. The other should be `#flash`. 2nd, it works but it's too fast. Setting timeout (using JavaScript `setTimeout()`) for 200 milliseconds (=0.2 sec) make the effect visible.

```js
$('#add').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.base').addClass('extra');
  }
)

$('#remove').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.base').removeClass('extra');
  }
)

$('#flash').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.base').addClass('extra');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.base').removeClass('extra');
    }, 200);
  }
)
```

```css
.base {
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000000;
  transition: 1.5s background-color;
}

.base.extra {
  transition: 0s background-color;
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='base'></div>
<a id='add'>Add 'extra' class</a><br/>
<a id='remove'>Remove 'extra' class</a><br/>
<a id='flash'>Add then remove 'extra' class</a><br/>
```

Comment: 200 is not 2 sec but 200 millisecondes

Comment: I used 10 ms in the end, but that's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this differently. Here is an idea with pseudo element.

```css
.base {
  width:300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position:relative;
}
.base:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:-1;
 background-color: #00ff00;
}
.base:hover::before {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 1.5s opacity;
}
```

```html
<div class='base'></div>
```

The same effect by adding/removing a class. You can rely on `transitionend` event to remove the class:

```js
$('.base').on(
  'click',
  function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('extra').on('transitionend', function () {
      $(this).removeClass('extra');
    });
  }
)
```

```css
.base {
  width:300px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000000;
  position:relative;
}
.base:before {
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 z-index:-1;
 background-color: #00ff00;
}
.base.extra::before {
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 1.5s opacity;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='base'></div>
```